# Images in Razor Class Library

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor, .net-core

Is it possible to use images and other file types such as css/js/etc. in a Razor Class library?  I'm having an issue trying to get the images and css in the Razor Class Library to show up in a .Net Core 2.1 MVC application.

We used to use the File Provider and a C# class library but I feel like the Razor Class Library should be able to accomplish this now by simply adding a reference to the library in a project.

Comment: There is an answer to your question in another thread. https://stackoverflow.com/a/53024912/1780760

Answer (score 12):

- make wwwroot folder on razor class library project and inside it images folder and insert your images on it to invoke the image on view component or out side project you need to make the path like this
- src="_content/rclProjectName/images/ajax-load.gif"
- link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/ui-class?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio