# Static Content in RazorClassLibraries with multiple resx files

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.2, razor-class-library

In my Razor Class Library I need to include static files like js and css files.

I followed the solution of the question 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/53024912/8687825. My project setup differs a bit. I have two resx files for different languages included.
The compiling of the projects fails with following error:

```
Error   MSB4018 The "GenerateEmbeddedResourcesManifest" task failed unexpectedly.
System.InvalidOperationException: An item with the name '' already exists.
```

And here is the csproj file

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>   
    <NeutralLanguage>de</NeutralLanguage>
    <GenerateEmbeddedFilesManifest>true</GenerateEmbeddedFilesManifest>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Embedded" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor" Version="$(MicrosoftNETSdkRazorPackageVersion)" PrivateAssets="All" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="12.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Telerik.UI.for.AspNet.Core" Version="2019.1.115" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="wwwroot\**\*" />
    <Content Update="**\*.cshtml" Pack="false" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Update="Properties\Resources.Designer.cs">
      <DesignTime>True</DesignTime>
      <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
      <DependentUpon>Resources.resx</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <EmbeddedResource Update="Properties\Resources.en.resx">
      <Generator>PublicResXFileCodeGenerator</Generator>
    </EmbeddedResource>
    <EmbeddedResource Update="Properties\Resources.resx">
      <Generator>PublicResXFileCodeGenerator</Generator>
      <LastGenOutput>Resources.Designer.cs</LastGenOutput>
    </EmbeddedResource>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

To avoid the Exception I have to name the resource files. But how do they get named? Or is there a wrong configuration in my project?

Comment: Have you found a solution for this?

Comment: Not yet. The static files are located in the main project.