# How to use JavaScript NuGet libraries in ASP.Net Core project correctly on the example MathJax?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, nuget, mathjax

I installed MathJax library for my site on ASP.Net Core from Package Manager.
I have seen `'MathJax (2.7.0)'` in NuGet Dependencies:


[Image of My Dependencies](https://c.mql5.com/2/35/image__51.png)

But is it all. When I see `wwwroot\lib` directory in my project I don't see `'MathJax'` folder or something similar in it:


[Image of My fron-end lib](https://c.mql5.com/2/35/image__52.png)

But when I need use MathJax I need write something similar in my html-page:


`<script type="text/javascript" async src="~lib/MathJax/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_HTML-full"></script>`

I can't copy NuGet library directly in `wwwroot\lib`, because I don't want to add my git repository a lot of files external project (> 36 Mb, > 1500 files). Besides, why use NuGet then?
Also, I can't add existing items of MathJax NuGet library manually (menu `Add -> Existing Item...`), because they are a lot and the absolute path will not correctly on another PC.


How I can get correctly link on MathJax library in NuGet package?

Comment: Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53024912/10208065), you need to use a *ConfigureOptions*.

Answer (score 6):

The JavaScript/CSS library NuGet packages are not for Core. They're for MVC. ASP.NET Core has a completely different approach to static files and client-side libraries than ASP.NET MVC did.

For an ASP.NET Core site, you need to use either LibMan or npm to get your client-side libraries. LibMan is easier, but also very naive and limited. In particular, it only supports libraries that are on cdnjs. While there's a lot of coverage there, it's not comprehensive, and there's some libraries that just are available. I'm not sure whether your particular library is or not.

However, given that you'll almost inevitably end up needing something you can't get through LibMan, and and then you'll be forced to use npm anyways, you might as well just use npm and get used to it. There's more of a learning curve because you also need to create build tasks with something like Webpack, Gulp, Grunt, etc. The npm packages go into a `node_modules` folder, which should not be served directly. At the very least, you'll need to use Webpack, Gulp, etc. to copy the dist/build of the npm package (i.e. the actual JS/CSS files that you'll be referencing) into your `wwwroot/lib` directory. There's lots of guides online for how to set this up. Just do some research.

Comment: Thanks so much. I found a good article for your answer: https://metanit.com/sharp/aspnet5/13.7.php

Comment: While Libman is still limited, it does now support packages on your filesystem, jsdelivr, unpkg as well as cdnjs.

Answer (score 5):

In the VS2019, go to the `wwwroot/lib` directory,  right click and select `Add -> Client-Side Library`.  then include your file.

Comment: this appears to be using Libman in the background

Answer (score 1):

Go to the web project, right click and go the manage client scripts, then search your library and instal.

Comment: Thanks. Add: this option is available in Visual Studio above 15.8 (2017) (I had to update my Studio).