# CSS from Blazor Component Lib not loaded

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, blazor

I want to use my customs CSS located on the `wwwroot/css/.` in my `BlazorControllers/Components/.` files but nothing is loaded at execution.
Is there something to specify in the client or in the lib project settings ?

My Library project is `BlazorControllers` and I use the component of the library in the Client project

[image]

Comment: 1. Did you add `<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/MyComponents.css" />` in your main page (e.g. `_Host.cshtml`) ?  2. Is that `BlazorControllers` project  a Razor Class Library?

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51610513/can-razor-class-library-pack-static-files-js-css-etc-too

Comment: @itminus it didn't work using `~/css/MyComponents.css` but worked well with `_content/BlazorControllers/css/MyComponents.css` path. I don't know what's the difference between both.

Comment: `_content` is a pseudofolder configured to get the files from somewhere (by the StaticFiles middleware). Compare with `_framework` for the main js file at the bottom of Index.html .

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your Index.html (or _Host.cshtml) file, below the site.css line, add

```
<link href="_content/<YourLibrary>/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

where `<YourLibrary>` seems to be BlazorControllers in your case.

And when I read that picture right you (also) need

```
<link href="_content/BlazorControllers/css/MyComponents.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Comment: I added a css library to indext.html (mine is client side app). But when I run the application I don't see the css link in the page source. Any idea? I checked the css file has build operation set to content, so isn't it supposed to be added?