# Blazor Shared Components not rendered

Tags: shared-libraries, blazor, webassembly

I have a problem, and I can't find a solution. This question is maybe already solved a couple of times, but it's hard to find a working solution for my constellation.

I'm using Blazor wasm 3.2.0-preview3.20168.3'. My goal is to move my components in a shared library to use it across my projects.

The problem is my components are not going to be rendered if I'm moving them into a shared library, so the tag `<alert><alert/>` is not resolved. The browser displays `<alert><alert/>`.

If they are in the main project, everything is working fine.

In the main project in  "_Imports.razor" the dependencies are imported

```
@using BlazingWebShared.Services
@using BlazingWebShared.Component
```

My library `.csproj` looks more or less like this (not including comments etc):

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>netstandard2.1</TargetFramework>
        <AddRazorSupportForMvc>true</AddRazorSupportForMvc>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly" Version="3.2.0-preview3.20168.3" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Build" Version="3.2.0-preview3.20168.3" PrivateAssets="all" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.DevServer" Version="3.2.0-preview3.20168.3" PrivateAssets="all" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.HttpClient" Version="3.2.0-preview3.20168.3" />
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Does someone have an idea what I'm doing wrong? Or can someone share a library I can use as a blueprint?

Thank you very much for your time and help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line

```
<AddRazorSupportForMvc>true</AddRazorSupportForMvc>
```

tells me that you checked "support for pages and views" when you created your Razor Class Library (RCL). Make a new one without that check. You get a very different project setup with or without that checkmark. Amongst other things it will target the wrong platform, core 3.x instead of standard 2.x

[image: screenshot]

And don't forget that you also have to import the .css and maybe .js files from the RCL into your _Host.razor or Index.cshtml . See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59609551/60761) for that.