# BlazorWebAssembly 5.0 does not load static assets from Razor class library

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-2019, blazor, razor-class-library

**Note:** [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60040793/404-with-static-content-in-razor-class-library-rcl) is not a duplicate.

After upgrading  to `.Net Core 5`, in `BlazorWebAssembly` the static assets(like `.js` or `.css`) from other class libraries(Razor class library projects) are not being served and face a `404` http status.

To test this I started with the default template example and added a Razor class library to it.I added `.css` file (test1.css) and as you can see the `.css` is not accessible. The same issue happened to my other projects.

(I have tested with both `Visual Studio 2019 16.8.1` and also `16.9.0 preview 1`)

[image]

resource not found :

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also have to: right click on the Dependencies folder, and select `Add Project Reference...`, and then tick the check-box for `RazorClassLibrary1`

Comment: would you please answer this question too : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64818508/blazor-webassembly-version-5-build-error-after-migration