# Blazor WebAssembly version 5 build error after migration

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly

After [migrating](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/31-to-50?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio) to `.Net Core 5` my standalone `BlazorWebAssembly` project could not be build and have the following error, I tried so many thing but it did not fixed.

> NETSDK1082    There was no runtime pack for Microsoft.AspNetCore.App available for the specified RuntimeIdentifier 'browser-wasm'.    MyProjectName C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.100\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.FrameworkReferenceResolution.targets 387

(I have tested with both `Visual Studio 2019 16.8.1` and also `16.9.0 preview 1`)

**Update:** I found the origin of the problem. If I remove the following package everything works fine. I  fact I tested with a default `Blazor` example template in Visual Studio and added the following package and get again the error. But **why**?

```
   /* version 3.1.9 and 3.1.10 have the same problem too*/
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer" Version="5.0.0" />
```

Comment: Did you check [blazor target framework changed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/3.1-5.0#blazor-target-framework-of-nuget-packages-changed) ?

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski Yes, I have altered all packages to their latest version. Most of them were 5.0.0 .

Comment: Did you clean and rebuild ?

Comment: @aguafrommars question updated

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski question updated

Comment: @nAviD, I saw your comment... I'll try to help if I can...