# Blazor proj from scratch+nuget: "There was no runtime pack for Microsoft.AspNetCore.App available for the specified RuntimeIdentifier 'browser-wasm'"

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-client-side, blazor-webassembly

**[Final update 07.12.2020 23:50 --> for everyone seeking for the anwser]**

You are probably adding some nuget package which has in fields DEPENDENCIES .NET Core 3.1. For example Serilog.AspNetCore 3.4.0. In this very example you can include Serilog.AspNetCore 3.2.0 because it has in DEPENDENCIES only .NetStandard 2.0. See more explanation in @Ogglas answer.

There is not enough space on earth to ask the one and only question: "Why, o why Microsoft?":) The message is not clearly correlating issue with the solution - this is the lightest euphemism i am capable of making :)

For me, Blazor is very promising but it is still more a beta version. And not only for me. The startblazoring guys are claiming, that Blazor can be fickle sometimes. And I cannot agree more;) I am keeping finger crossed for it. But I suppose it would be a "ready product" only after .NET 6.0.

**[Original Topic]**

This is so frustrating :)

I hate errors, when I cannot simply interact and understood where it is coming from. I know, I am ignorant, and If I would pay more attention to "how is the blazor app created" I would understand in eye blink.

But for now it is only frustrating. What is? The error message:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error   NETSDK1082  There was no runtime pack for Microsoft.AspNetCore.App available for the specified RuntimeIdentifier 'browser-wasm'.    TestBlazorAppNoRuntimeError.Client  C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.100\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.FrameworkReferenceResolution.targets   387

Really, what can you fix here?:D Ehhhhh. I understand that .NET 5 is a "new thing". I understand Blazor is a "new thing" But really? It is really easy to "break" ;) (with a message that is saying nothing)

So what did I do?

Did I create very complicated project with hundreds of thousands of files?

**No**

Did I add hundreds of thousands of nuget packages.

**No**

All it takes is to create Blazor Webassembly app and add one nuget package to the shared (common) library (FYI: IdentityServer4 package). That is all folks. Kudos if you would now, that this package specificly is causing this issue (because i found out only by mistake):

> There was no runtime pack for Microsoft.AspNetCore.App available for the specified RuntimeIdentifier 'browser-wasm'.

Really, there is a great correlation here: between the error message and the package being added (this was sarcasm if anyone missed it:) )

So if you want to reproduce it create create "Blazor Webassembly":

[image]

I don't suppose the options chosen are making the difference. But if this is the case - you can see what option I did choose. Then just add IdentityServer4 nuget package to shared library:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/IdentityServer4/

That is all

If you are too lazy - download this project and check for yourself:

https://ufile.io/751l5wgq

I saw hundreds of SOF topics regarding this message:

> There was no runtime pack for Microsoft.AspNetCore.App available for the specified RuntimeIdentifier 'browser-wasm'.

But none of those was so easy to reproduce.

Why I am creating this topic?

Because I did try to implement (by copy-pasting to my solution) what guys did create in Blazor boilerplate here:
https://github.com/enkodellc/blazorboilerplate

At the beginning, by mistake, I've added Identity4 NuGet instead of Identity4.storage and that is why I did observe such behavior (such error) and did correlate this package with this error. When I rolled back from Identity4 to Identity4.storage everything was correct once again. But after that I did a lot of code transfer from this repository. And once I've ended, right now, everything is compiling but once again I have:

> There was no runtime pack for Microsoft.AspNetCore.App available for the specified RuntimeIdentifier 'browser-wasm'.

And it is driving me crazy. Maybe you would have some idea, how to find out WHAT is causing this error (exactly the same as previously Identity4 nuget package was causing it)

**[UPDATE 06.12.2020 12:30]**

The question here is more: "Why is it happening and how to locate package causing the issue" I know that I can second guess what is causing this message to appear.

I did a little investigation. This error is showing in this target:

```
<ResolveRuntimePackAssets FrameworkReferences="@(FrameworkReference)"
                          ResolvedRuntimePacks="@(ResolvedRuntimePack)"
                          UnavailableRuntimePacks="@(UnavailableRuntimePack)"
                          SatelliteResourceLanguages="$(SatelliteResourceLanguages)"
                          DesignTimeBuild="$(DesignTimeBuild)">
  <Output TaskParameter="RuntimePackAssets" ItemName="RuntimePackAsset" />
</ResolveRuntimePackAssets>

<ItemGroup>
  <ReferenceCopyLocalPaths Include="@(RuntimePackAsset)"
                           Condition="'$(CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies)' == 'true' and ('$(SelfContained)' == 'true' or '%(RuntimePackAsset.RuntimePackAlwaysCopyLocal)' == 'true')" />
</ItemGroup>
```

so I did google ResolveRuntimePackAssets and found this repo and this file:

https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/blob/release/5.0.2xx/src/Tasks/Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks/ResolveRuntimePackAssets.cs and such code:

```
foreach (var unavailableRuntimePack in UnavailableRuntimePacks)
{
    if (frameworkReferenceNames.Contains(unavailableRuntimePack.ItemSpec))
    {
        //  This is a runtime pack that should be used, but wasn't available for the specified RuntimeIdentifier
        //  NETSDK1082: There was no runtime pack for {0} available for the specified RuntimeIdentifier '{1}'.
        Log.LogError(Strings.NoRuntimePackAvailable, unavailableRuntimePack.ItemSpec,
            unavailableRuntimePack.GetMetadata(MetadataKeys.RuntimeIdentifier));
    }
}
```

Looks like the code "causing" the issue (this calls for writing down information in message about: `unavailableRuntimePack.ItemSpec` - it would be so much easier;))

So right now the only thing is to locate what is filling this: `UnavailableRuntimePacks` property. I don't see any code doing that so it have to be some reflection. I've located this code which is probably doing it:

https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/blob/release/5.0.2xx/src/Tasks/Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks/ProcessFrameworkReferences.cs

And this method:

```
private void ProcessRuntimeIdentifier(
    string runtimeIdentifier,
    KnownRuntimePack selectedRuntimePack,
    string runtimePackVersion,
    List<string> additionalFrameworkReferencesForRuntimePack,
    HashSet<string> unrecognizedRuntimeIdentifiers,
    List<ITaskItem> unavailableRuntimePacks,
    List<ITaskItem> runtimePacks,
    List<ITaskItem> packagesToDownload,
    string isTrimmable,
    bool addToPackageDownload)
{
    var runtimeGraph = new RuntimeGraphCache(this).GetRuntimeGraph(RuntimeGraphPath);
    var knownFrameworkReferenceRuntimePackRuntimeIdentifiers = selectedRuntimePack.RuntimePackRuntimeIdentifiers.Split(';');

    string runtimePackRuntimeIdentifier = NuGetUtils.GetBestMatchingRid(
            runtimeGraph,
            runtimeIdentifier,
            knownFrameworkReferenceRuntimePackRuntimeIdentifiers,
            out bool wasInGraph);

    if (runtimePackRuntimeIdentifier == null)
    {
        if (wasInGraph)
        {
            //  Report this as an error later, if necessary.  This is because we try to download
            //  all available runtime packs in case there is a transitive reference to a shared
            //  framework we don't directly reference.  But we don't want to immediately error out
            //  here if a runtime pack that we might not need to reference isn't available for the
            //  targeted RID (e.g. Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App for a linux RID).
            var unavailableRuntimePack = new TaskItem(selectedRuntimePack.Name);
            unavailableRuntimePack.SetMetadata(MetadataKeys.RuntimeIdentifier, runtimeIdentifier);
            unavailableRuntimePacks.Add(unavailableRuntimePack);
        }
        else if (!unrecognizedRuntimeIdentifiers.Contains(runtimeIdentifier))
        {
            //  NETSDK1083: The specified RuntimeIdentifier '{0}' is not recognized.
            Log.LogError(Strings.RuntimeIdentifierNotRecognized, runtimeIdentifier);
            unrecognizedRuntimeIdentifiers.Add(runtimeIdentifier);
        }
    }
    else if (addToPackageDownload)
    {
        foreach (var runtimePackNamePattern in selectedRuntimePack.RuntimePackNamePatterns.Split(';'))
        {
            string runtimePackName = runtimePackNamePattern.Replace("**RID**", runtimePackRuntimeIdentifier);

            if (runtimePacks != null)
            {
                TaskItem runtimePackItem = new TaskItem(runtimePackName);
                runtimePackItem.SetMetadata(MetadataKeys.NuGetPackageId, runtimePackName);
                runtimePackItem.SetMetadata(MetadataKeys.NuGetPackageVersion, runtimePackVersion);
                runtimePackItem.SetMetadata(MetadataKeys.FrameworkName, selectedRuntimePack.Name);
                runtimePackItem.SetMetadata(MetadataKeys.RuntimeIdentifier, runtimePackRuntimeIdentifier);
                runtimePackItem.SetMetadata(MetadataKeys.IsTrimmable, isTrimmable);

                if (selectedRuntimePack.RuntimePackAlwaysCopyLocal)
                {
                    runtimePackItem.SetMetadata(MetadataKeys.RuntimePackAlwaysCopyLocal, "true");
                }

                if (additionalFrameworkReferencesForRuntimePack != null)
                {
                    runtimePackItem.SetMetadata(MetadataKeys.AdditionalFrameworkReferences, string.Join(";", additionalFrameworkReferencesForRuntimePack));
                }

                runtimePacks.Add(runtimePackItem);
            }

            TaskItem packageToDownload = new TaskItem(runtimePackName);
            packageToDownload.SetMetadata(MetadataKeys.Version, runtimePackVersion);

            packagesToDownload.Add(packageToDownload);
        }
    }
}
```

After analysing it, the reason why Identity4 (for example) is causing this issue is because runtimePackRuntimeIdentifier is null and wasInGraph was true :) But what does mean, we have to dig a little bit further. The key thing here is the method GetBestMatchingRid:

```
public static string GetBestMatchingRid(RuntimeGraph runtimeGraph, string runtimeIdentifier,
    IEnumerable<string> availableRuntimeIdentifiers, out bool wasInGraph)
{
    wasInGraph = runtimeGraph.Runtimes.ContainsKey(runtimeIdentifier);

    HashSet<string> availableRids = new HashSet<string>(availableRuntimeIdentifiers);
    foreach (var candidateRuntimeIdentifier in runtimeGraph.ExpandRuntime(runtimeIdentifier))
    {
        if (availableRids.Contains(candidateRuntimeIdentifier))
        {
            return candidateRuntimeIdentifier;
        }
    }

    //  No compatible RID found in availableRuntimeIdentifiers
    return null;
}
```

So here we see that `runtimePackRuntimeIdentifier` was null because it was not found on: `availableRuntimeIdentifiers`. And this variable is defined as:

`var knownFrameworkReferenceRuntimePackRuntimeIdentifiers = selectedRuntimePack.RuntimePackRuntimeIdentifiers.Split(';');`

So let's see how is it defined (in the code below variable `runtimePackForRuntimeIDProcessing` is `selectedRuntimePack` from the above mention)

```
KnownRuntimePack runtimePackForRuntimeIDProcessing;
if (knownFrameworkReference.Name.Equals(knownFrameworkReference.RuntimeFrameworkName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
{
    //  Only add runtime packs where the framework reference name matches the RuntimeFrameworkName
    //  Framework references for "profiles" will use the runtime pack from the corresponding non-profile framework
    runtimePackForRuntimeIDProcessing = selectedRuntimePack.Value;
    includeInPackageDownload = true;
}
else if (!knownFrameworkReference.RuntimePackRuntimeIdentifiers.Equals(selectedRuntimePack?.RuntimePackRuntimeIdentifiers))
{
    // If the profile has a different set of runtime identifiers than the runtime pack, use the profile.
    runtimePackForRuntimeIDProcessing = knownFrameworkReference.ToKnownRuntimePack();
    includeInPackageDownload = true;
}
else
{
    // For the remaining profiles, don't include them in package download but add them to unavaliable if necessary.
    runtimePackForRuntimeIDProcessing = knownFrameworkReference.ToKnownRuntimePack();
    includeInPackageDownload = false;
}
```

But this is as far as I can go. I don't understand without further investigation how this `selectedRuntimePack.RuntimePackRuntimeIdentifiers` should be defined. This is the key thing here. Clearly for some reasons IdentityServer4 doesn't belong to `selectedRuntimePack.RuntimePackRuntimeIdentifiers` and this is the answer I am looking for :)

Comment: This happens when you run it in Visual Studio right? We are not talking about after deployment to a server.

Comment: You have repro steps. Go and try ;) But to answer your question. No. It is not after deployment, It is build in VS 2019 16.8.2  :) I even did try in 16.9.0 1.0 preview. It is the same.

Comment: _(FYI: IdentityServer4 package)_ that does not belong in the Shared Project. Add it to the Server project only.

Comment: @HenkHolterman - my question was more like --> how to discover which nuget package is preventing the solution to compile. Identity4 - I did discover it by accident. 

Right now in my project I also have this issue, but I have no idea which package is causing it.

And what exactly is causing Identity4 package a package, that, I quote: "Does not belong in shared project" If I see packages I want to add to Shared project, how will I know if something "belong in shared project" or not?

Comment: _how will I know if something "belong in shared project" or not?_ By understanding what the projects are used for and on which runtime they run. Blazor/Wasm does not support everything. NuGet does not know how to hold your hand here.

Comment: @HenkHolterman - so i am repeating my question once again. How to check whether nuget package will run on wasm. And even simpler question. You have 100 nuget packages included in your blazor client project (or shared project) and solution is not compiling with message mentioned in the topic. How will you know which package is causing this issue? Because till now you are only trying to convince me, that "it is ok" So something like "it is a feature not a bug" :)

Comment: You don't put 100 packages in a Client project. The Shared Project is included in the Client so for both: add as little as possible and only what you know to be alright. Assume it isn't and investigate ort test.

Comment: You are right that there is no complete documentation and no tooling (afaik). But a little common sense goes a long way.

Comment: @HenkHolterman - i suppose we should end this pointless discussion :) You simply don't have the solution for this problem. Maybe someone would have - so I will wait for such person. I agree that I can right now remove packages one by one and comment all the code in project (because it will not compile while I do it....) or to create mirror solution where I will only have packages and no code. The same way as I can code in notepad. Fun is the same :) Hopefully someone will came with some clear solution to this problem.

Comment: With .NET 6 preview 4: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67747701/net-6-preview-4-there-was-no-runtime-pack-for-microsoft-aspnetcore-app-availab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IdentityServer4 4.1.1` (latest version) is dependent upon `.NETCoreApp 3.1`

https://www.nuget.org/packages/IdentityServer4/

If you create a `Blazor WebAssembly App` using `.NET Core 3.1` it will work in the `Server` App.

[image]

However when using `.NET Core 3.1` both `Client` and `Shared` uses `.NET Standard 2.1` and is therefore not compatible. These error messages are a lot clearar though:

> Error     Package restore failed. Rolling back package changes for
> 'BlazorApp.Shared'.

> Error NU1202 Package IdentityServer4 4.1.1 is not compatible with
> netstandard2.1 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.1). Package IdentityServer4
> 4.1.1 supports: netcoreapp3.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1)  BlazorApp.Shared

Comment: I am using .NET 5.0. apart of that you are correct.You was the closest to the solution i suppose. It turns out - you CANNOT include packages with .NET CORE 3.1 marked as Dependency on nuget package DEPENDENCIES section. Another good example is Serilog.AspNetCore 3.4.0 It has as Dependencies .NETCoreApp version 3.1. So will have the same error I was facing if you would try to include this package. But you can include Serilog.AspNetCore 3.2.0 as it has dependencies to .NETStandard version 2.0. I ask only ONE QUESTION. Why is it not put on my face every time I am trying to include such package...

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64818508/blazor-webassembly-version-5-build-error-after-migration), it seems there is an issue regarding to the following package. So remove the package from your project and every other project that has been referenced by your Blazor project(right-click on project, choose edit project file then remove the following):

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer" Version="5.0.0" />
```

In my case (and hopefully in yours too) the only use of this package was the get the constant string `"Bearer"` with the field member `JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme`. So instead of this just simply use `"Bearer"` string.

Comment: For sure you were facing the same issue. But you didn't receive any answer WHY and HOW to diagnose this package, that is causing this issue. You found the issue by second guessing the package to remove. This is always an option, but ultimately we are engineers. We are getting paid for knowing things not guessing things;) I would like to know what is causing this issue more than overcome it.

Comment: The approach that talking  about is not optimized for better productivity. As a consumer of a software product, this is not for us to solve the issues and bugs. We can only report the issues and they should solve it. Don't waste your precious time on these issues, this is not engineering. Put your time and effort on relevant problems.

Comment: sorry, it is "my thing" I like to know. And here the issue is (as it turns out), that nuget packages, that has in DEPENDENCIES .Net Core 3.1 will not work :) Crazy, I know. But right now I will know, that if I would want to include some package in Blazor project to check "dependencies" ;)

Comment: I'm stuck on the same boat. Or, is it I'm stuck "in" the same boat. Anyways. This definitely sounds like a major bug still in .Net 7, VS2022 so I presume it's something people who maintain the identity NuGet stuff have to do. I went down a couple different routes like you did, but I tend to agree with nAviD. Seeing that it still haven't gotten their attention, we just have to scream louder. That, is what we should do.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue while working on a blazor wasm/server/shared projects. In my case, I narrowed down the issue to the project sdk types:

Client.csproj:

```
    <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BlazorWebAssembly">
```

Server.csproj:

```
    <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
```

Shared.csproj definition causing the issue:

```
    <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor">
```

Shared.csproj definition without issue:

```
    <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
```

The client wasm project did not like that the shared one was declared as Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor and had to change it to Microsoft.NET.Sdk in order to get rid of the error in the title.

I still need to dig further in to better understand the full differences between those two project types but I hope this can help anyone else facing this issue.