# .NET 6 preview 4: There was no runtime pack for Microsoft.AspNetCore.App available for the specified RuntimeIdentifier 'browser-wasm'

Tags: asp.net-core, nuget, identityserver4, blazor-webassembly, asp.net-core-scaffolding

I am using .NET `6.0.100-preview.4.21255.9` , ASP.NET Core Blazor WebAssembly `6.0.100-preview.4.21255.9` . I try to override default Identity UI by this way: Add reference to NuGet package ]`Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI/6.0.0-preview.4.21253.5?_src=template) but error happen when add this NuGet package (another NuGet packages were ok)

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   NETSDK1082  There was no runtime pack for Microsoft.AspNetCore.App available for the specified RuntimeIdentifier 'browser-wasm'.    acc.Client  C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.100-preview.4.21255.9\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.FrameworkReferenceResolution.targets 391 
Error   NETSDK1082  There was no runtime pack for Microsoft.AspNetCore.App available for the specified RuntimeIdentifier 'browser-wasm'.    acc.Client  C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.100-preview.4.21255.9\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.FrameworkReferenceResolution.targets 391
```

Main error information:

```
There was no runtime pack for Microsoft.AspNetCore.App available for the specified RuntimeIdentifier 'browser-wasm'
```

[image]

When I click to see detail error, it pointed to

```xml
<ResolveRuntimePackAssets FrameworkReferences="@(FrameworkReference)"
                          ResolvedRuntimePacks="@(ResolvedRuntimePack)"
                          UnavailableRuntimePacks="@(UnavailableRuntimePack)"
                          SatelliteResourceLanguages="$(SatelliteResourceLanguages)"
                          DesignTimeBuild="$(DesignTimeBuild)">
  <Output TaskParameter="RuntimePackAssets" ItemName="RuntimePackAsset" />
</ResolveRuntimePackAssets>
```

(File `C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.100-preview.4.21255.9\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.DefaultItems.targets` . Excerpt from https://gist.github.com/donhuvy/d98d59e8af9947e37e6d4fe85004e444#file-microsoft-net-sdk-frameworkreferenceresolution-targets-L391-L397 )

How to add NuGet package UI success?

Comment: Exact same problem, any solutions available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Upgrade to new/latest versions of .NET
- Clear cache in web browser
- Delete old build fodlers (`obj`, `bin`), clean/Re-build Solution.