# Using StaticFileOptions() breaks embedded static files from Razor Class Library

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, razor-class-library

I'm trying to add long cache headers to static .css and .js files using `StaticFileOptions`

From various SO and other articles, this is how you do it:

```
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
{
    OnPrepareResponse = ctx =>
    {
        const int durationInSeconds = 60 * 60 * 24;
        ctx.Context.Response.Headers[HeaderNames.CacheControl] =
        "public,max-age=" + durationInSeconds;
    }
});
```

However, I am using a bunch of static files provided by a RCL. The RCL has a StaticServing.cs class which I have used from this article: [Can Razor Class Library pack static files (js, css etc) too?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51610513/can-razor-class-library-pack-static-files-js-css-etc-too)

For the sake of completeness to my question, this class is as follows:

```
public StaticServing(IHostingEnvironment environment)
    {
        Environment = environment;
    }
    public IHostingEnvironment Environment { get; }

    public void PostConfigure(string name, StaticFileOptions options)
    {
        name = name ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(name));
        options = options ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(options));

        // Basic initialization in case the options weren't initialized by any other component
        options.ContentTypeProvider = options.ContentTypeProvider ?? new FileExtensionContentTypeProvider();
        if (options.FileProvider == null && Environment.WebRootFileProvider == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Missing FileProvider.");
        }

        options.FileProvider = options.FileProvider ?? Environment.WebRootFileProvider; 

        string basePath = "Static";

        ManifestEmbeddedFileProvider filesProvider = new ManifestEmbeddedFileProvider(GetType().Assembly, basePath);
        options.FileProvider = new CompositeFileProvider(options.FileProvider, filesProvider);
    }
}
```

in the consuming projects startup.cs I have `services.ConfigureOptions(typeof(StaticServing));` and the RCL has `<GenerateEmbeddedFilesManifest>true</GenerateEmbeddedFilesManifest>`  and `<EmbeddedResource Include="Static\**\*" />` settings.

With this all in place everything works... **UNLESS** I add the `StaticFileOptions` code at the start of the question, in which case, all references to the embedded static files return `404`.

I have tried adding:

- `FileProvider = env.ContentRootFileProvider` and
- `FileProvider = env.WebRootFileProvider`

To the `StaticFileOptions` setting, but that isn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The static files middleware can receive its `StaticFileOptions` in one of two ways:

1. Implicitly via Dependency Injection.
2. Explicitly via the call to `UseStaticFiles`.

In your problematic scenario, you're (inadvertently) attempting to configure the middleware using both of these approaches. As soon as you add an argument to the `UseStaticFiles` call, you're *replacing* the framework-provided configuration for the middleware, which includes setup for RCL support.

To build on the framework-provided configuration, you can take advantage of the options pattern in `ConfigureServices`:

```
services.Configure<StaticFileOptions>(options =>
{
    options.OnPrepareResponse = ctx =>
    {
        const int durationInSeconds = 60 * 60 * 24;
        ctx.Context.Response.Headers[HeaderNames.CacheControl] =
            "public, max-age=" + durationInSeconds;
    }  
});
```

You'll also need to remove the argument being passed to `UseStaticFiles`.