# .NET Core publish folders in wrong location

Tags: c#, .net-core, publish

My project is split up in several smaller libraries each doing it's own part (one for the views, one for some logic, ...)

This all gets loaded and initialized in `main-project.csproj`.

When debugging, every screen is loaded correctly.

However when I publish the folder is not generated as expected. I'm using the following publish command:

```
dotnet publish ..\..\main-project.csproj -r win10-x64 -c Release -o publish\
```

Release folder main-project:

```
win10-x64/
├─ Properties/
│  ├─ launchSettings.json
├─ Views/
│  ├─ _ViewStart.cshtml
│  ├─ ...
├─ wwwroot/
│  ├─ favicon.ico
│  ├─ ...
├─ some.service.exe
├─ some.service.dll
├─ ...
```

Published folder

```
publish/

├─ wwwroot/
│  ├─ _content/
│  │  ├─ ClientService/
│  │  │  ├─ favicon.ico
│  │  │  ├─ ...
├─ some.service.dll
├─ some.service.exe
├─ ...
```

As you can see, the `Views` and `Properties` folders are missing, and my `wwwroot` folder has several subfolders generated.

I have no idea on how to resolve this. So any suggestions are more than welcome

Comment: Can you help us understand what files you are missing in your published directory? `Views` contains source code, which is compiled into your dll. The `launchSettings.json` file is for development and not needed in the final built project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was resolved by including the following in the library project:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <StaticWebAssetBasePath Condition="$(StaticWebAssetBasePath) == ''">/</StaticWebAssetBasePath>
</PropertyGroup>
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/59574845/1229158