# ASP.NET Core MVC web app using RCL (NuGet package)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, razor-class-library

The base application (`MyTestApp`) is an ASP.NET Core MVC web app (based on the default template). In addition, a Razor Class Library (RCL) has been created (`MyRazorClassLibrary`). The css, js and lib folders of the `MyTestApp` are moved to `wwwroot` folder of the RCL.

`MyRazorClassLibrary` is a NuGet package which has been added to `MyTestApp`.

I've read and tried several solutions about static files in a RCL, but none of them seem to work properly. The files are loaded in `MyTestApp`, but are NOT (?!) visible (as linked reference) in Visual Studio 2022. In addition, I need to publish `MyTestApp` first in order to load the css, js files and run the app localhost?

Could you point me in the right direction and/or provide a .NET 6 demo app (which contains the described example)?

Default csproj of RCL:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
  </PropertyGroup>
    
  <ItemGroup>
    <SupportedPlatform Include="browser" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web" Version="6.0.10" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Modified csproj of RCL (doesn't work):

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <GeneratePackageOnBuild>True</GeneratePackageOnBuild>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <SupportedPlatform Include="browser" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
      <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Embedded" Version="6.0.16" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: Please refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51610513/can-razor-class-library-pack-static-files-js-css-etc-too)